# BMW E46 320D Battery Replacement

Tags: battery, bmw

My 5 year old battery is dying, and I'm looking for a replacement. When this one was fitted, the car wasn't mine yet. There's also no label on the top with some details.

Therefore, I wanted to know the recommended amperage and CCA (and possibly other values) for my car. It's a 2000 BMW E46 320D (136 cv). I've tried checking my manual but it doesn't specify the recommended values. 
If you guys also throw in things to look for when buying car batteries, I'd appreciated too!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good stores selling batteries have a list you can consult list Ah, CCA etc and physical dimensions.

Comment: See this example: https://www.batteriesplus.com.au/bmw-battery-fittment-guide/

Comment: [This might also be of assistance.](https://www.tayna.co.uk/BMW-3_Series-Car-Battery)

Comment: dont you have to get it registered as well?